# Is there a way to change realtime database field names when fetching them in a web app

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a firebase realtime database on my android app, and there is an option to change the naming of the fields of a class with PropertyName.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName

Is there a way to achieve something similar in a web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the names of the properties in the resulting object will always match the names of the children in the database.  If you don't want different property names in the object, you'll have to manually create a new object that looks the way you want.

Comment: So basically write my own mapping, thanks for the answer.